# how to summing the value from specific json object with several conditions (e.g. where value from object "TYPE" is "ABC")?

Tags: javascript, json

I've json like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.greenfields.co.id:502/service1.svc/id). in that json there is object name `tipe` and I want to sum `act_qty1`, `act_val1`, `acvqty`, `acvval`, `budqty`, `budval`, `cm_val1`, `cm_val2`, `cm_val3`  in the same tipe(e.g. sum them where their `tipe` is "ESL"). How to sum that in javascript? can it done with loop?

here is what I've made so far:

```
function detail(kodenegara, koderesult)
        {   
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://www.greenfields.co.id:502/Service1.svc/"+kodenegara,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var result = koderesult;

                    var details = "";

                    for (i = 0; i < data[result].length; i++){
                        $("#"+data[result][i].tipe).empty();
                    }
                    for (i = 0, types={} ; i < data[result].length; i++){
                        $("#"+data[result][i].tipe).append("<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].mc+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].value3+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].value2+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].value1+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].avgqty+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].budqty+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].budval+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].acvqty+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[result][i].acvval+"</td>"+
                          "</tr>").trigger('create');


                            //----------------------------------//
                            // HERE IS what I've made TO SUM THE VALUES //
                            //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv//

                           for(i = 0; i < data[result].length; i++) {
                    if(data[result][i].tipe == 'ESL') 
                    {
                        //how to summing data[result][i].cm_val3 where data[result][i].tipe == 'ESL'
                                        var b = i + 1;
                            var test = parseInt(data[result][i].cm_val3) + parseInt(data[result][b].cm_val3)
                    }
                }

                    }

                    //show the page
                    $.mobile.changePage("#detail_"+kodenegara, "slide", false, true);
                },
                error: function () { 
                    alert("ERROR"); 
                }
            });
        }
```

I don't know how to write the right looping for summing the value while `tipe` is "ESL" (or "ESL1L" or "WHP" or else). if I use this:

```
var b = i + 1;
var test = parseInt(data[result][i].cm_val3) + parseInt(data[result][b].cm_val3)
```

that only sum the last array. how to write the right looping to sum with that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here come a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xKJn8/1/

```
var SumByTipe = {};
for(i in data.GetReportIdResult){
    var currtipe = data.GetReportIdResult[i].tipe;
    if (currtipe){
        if (currtipe in SumByTipe){
            for (j in data.GetReportIdResult[i]){
                if (j != "tipe" && j != "mc"){
                    SumByTipe[currtipe][j + '_total'] += parseFloat(data.GetReportIdResult[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }else{
            var firstSum = {};
            for (j in data.GetReportIdResult[i]){
                if (j != "tipe" && j != "mc"){
                    firstSum[j + '_total'] = parseFloat(data.GetReportIdResult[i][j]);
                }
            }
            SumByTipe[currtipe]=firstSum;
        }
    }
}
console.debug(SumByTipe);
```

Comment: It works perfectly :D that's exactly just what I need. Thank you very much mate :)

Comment: Open firebug to see what printed out

Comment: Hello again :) thanks for the answer, but I've problem again, I want to divide some value from these summing by number of `mc` (e.g. If the number of `mc` is 5 then I want to do `parseFloat(SumByTipe['ESL']['cm1_per1_total])/5` ) how to do that? thanks :)

Comment: After having `SumByTipe` you can do a loop again to count `mc` and do what ever you want. the structure of loop will be similar to `for (j in data.GetReportIdResult[i]){if (j != "tipe" && j != "mc"){...` Good luck

Comment: I'm still confuse, where I should put that loop because I always get large number like 18, but it should be 6. :(

Comment: Take it easy, can you install firebug, try to print it out to console, you will see its structure and you can modify the code so it can run

Comment: finally I get it, and here is my update work http://jsfiddle.net/xKJn8/18/ :D thank you

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick :

```
var sum_cm_val3=0;

for (var i=0;i<data[result].length;i++) {
    if (data[result][i].tipe == "ESL") {
        var cm_val3 = data[result][i].cm_val3;
        if (parseInt(cm_val3)==cm_val3) {
            sum_cm_val3 += parseInt(cm_val3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you want to sum every fields except mc and tipe ?

Comment: yes, but in some case, I just want to do the thing with the code you have create before, so basically I need all the answers here :D